# Github pages not loading W3.CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a github page using the css stylesheet from W3.CSS.

However, when I try to load the page, it seems like no CSS stylesheet is loaded. I did not found an answer here on stackoverflow or anywhere else

Maybe I am doing something wrong, but I don't know what.

Here is the beggining of my index.html file

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3-theme-black.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<style>
html,body,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif}
.w3-sidenav a,.w3-sidenav h4 {padding: 12px;}
.w3-navbar li a {
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
}
</style>
<title>Amérique du Sud</title>
</head>
```

And here is [the page in question](https://laurenthayez.github.io/#Argentine)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look in the browser console you'll see an error

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://laurenthayez.github.io/#Argentine' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

That means that since your site is `https://`, it will not load resources that are served over `http://` for security reasons.

The solution is to use `https://www.w3schools.com/...` for your assets instead of `http://www.w3schools.com/...`. Or you can just use `//www.w3schools.com/...` and that will request the asset from the site using the same protocol as your site. Or in other words, if your website is `http://`, it will request `http://`, or if your website is `https://`, it will request `https://`

So change your `link` tags to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3-theme-black.css">
```

or

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//www.w3schools.com/lib/w3-theme-black.css">
```

Comment: Great! Thank you for the explanations and the help :-)

Comment: @LaurentHayez you bet :)